# This thing is giving me error. C Language

Tags: c

How can I fix this? I want to `scanf()` a value for d, how can I do it? I need some help please. Appreciate that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void LerDeputados(int d) {
    printf("Indique o número de deputados a repartir: ");
    scanf("%d",&d);
}
int main(void) {
    int d;
    LerDeputados(d);
    printf("%d",d);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error does it give you? I understand what you are asking in this case but you need to be more precise in your future posted questions.

Comment: When compiling the posted code, the compiler raises the warning that 'd' is used, uninitialised in the call to `LerDuputados()`.    But the real problem is that the call to LerDuputados() is passing the contents of 'd' rather than the address of 'd'

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that when you pass the variable `d` to your `LerDeputados` function, it's passed *by value*, which means that it is copied. The value is properly changed inside the function, but it's only changing the *copy*, and changing a copy will of course not change the original.

What you need to do here is to pass the variable *by reference*. Unfortunately C doesn't have that, but it can be emulated by using pointer. In other words, you need to pass a pointer to the variable `d` to your `LerDeputados` function.

Like

```
void LerDeputados(int *d) { ... }
```

Then call it with the address-of operator:

```
LerDeputados(&d);
```

Comment: Pointers are too advanced when you are learning. Let him learn without them first (see my answer for that @Congelador10). Nice explanations on the passing by value and passing by reference though. Upvote :)

Comment: @LBesancon Too advanced? I wouldn't expect to get anything even remotely useful done in C without pointers. It's like saying the clutch is too advanced when you're first learning to drive a manual car.

Comment: @LBesancon: He's already having to deal with a pointer in the `scanf` call.  You can't avoid them in beginner code.

Comment: @JohnBode Yes right, but beginners tend first to learn without pointers and what they mean. What I mean is like someone told him "this is how you use  scanf, don't ask why for now, we'll get to that later". So my point was to provide this kind of answer first not to mess with him.

Comment: and since 'd' in the LerDuputados() function will then be a pointer, the call to scanf() needs to be like this: `scanf("%d",d);`

Answer (score 2):

There are some errors in your code. First of all you need to return the value that you get from `scan` in the `LerDeputados(int d)` function. Also you need to assign this value to the `d` you create in your `main()` Change your code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int LerDeputados() {
    int d ;
    printf("Indique o número de deputados a repartir: ");
    scanf("%d",&d);
    return d ;
}
int main(void) {
    int d;
    d = LerDeputados();
    printf("%d",d);

    return 0;
}
```

Or you can use pointers (needs a more advanced level though)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void LerDeputados(int* pd) {
    printf("Indique o número de deputados a repartir: ");
    scanf("%d",pd);
}
int main(void) {
    int d;
    LerDeputados(&d);
    printf("%d",d);

    return 0;
}
```

My piece of advice would be to read some good C book before going further into the world of programming.

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: What's the use of passing uninitialized `d` to `LerDeputados` in your first solution.

Comment: There's no use I just forgot to edit the code first. Edit on the way

Comment: Better way is to change `LerDeputados` not to take any parameters in your first solution, and declare `d` as a local variable in `LerDeputados`.

Comment: Yeah yeah sorry, just forgot to change that (I definitely need some sleep). See the edit ;)

Comment: You may still need more sleep. Calling with `LerDeputados(d)`?

Comment: Indeed, thanks for helping the sleep-deprived programmer ^^'

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the basics of C..

Change the `scanf()` to

```
scanf("%d",&d);
```

**A little explanantion**

`scanf()` needs the address of the variable in which it will store the read value. An to get the address of an `int` variable, you the `&` operator before it.

That was to solve the error

---

Now, in your code, variable `d` in `void LerDeputados(int d)` is a local variable, which is completely different from the `d` in `main()`. This is happening because you are passing the vallue of `d` to `void LerDeputados(int d)`. You have to pass the address to `void LerDeputados()`.

Chnage your code to

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void LerDeputados(int* d) {
    printf("Indique o número de deputados a repartir: ");
    scanf("%d",d);
}
int main(void) {
    int d;
    LerDeputados(&d);
    printf("%d",d);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Forgot it. I fixed but it still returning value d=0.

Comment: @Congelador10 read Joachims answer, it explains it in another way.

Comment: @Congelador10 you can also refer to mine, with two solutions, the one with pointers and the one without pointers ;)